# Windows 7/10 - Find command prompt / script for RightClick -> Send to Application

Tags: shell, command-line, image-uploading

if i right click on an image while in the windows explorer i get the option to 'Send To Gyazo' which is an image sharing site. Is there a way i can get this command so that I can execute it via commandline or something of the sort.

What I am trying to do is whenever an image file is saved in a specific directory to automatically upload so I am exploring options to do this.

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser and it depends if the software provide commanline options to do so. You can check it's documentation or on the command line `gyazo /?` for options (assuming the executable is called `gyazo`.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.